# Error opening csv file in jupyter notebook

Tags: python

I created a csv file and closed it.
But, when I try to cast it into a list it gives me an error 'list' object is not callable.

Below is the codes for creating and opening the csv file:

```
file_to_output = open('to_save.csv',mode='w',newline='')

csv_writer = csv.writer(file_to_output,delimiter=',')

csv_writer = csv.writer(file_to_output,delimiter=',')

csv_writer.writerows([['6','8','7'],['3','1','2']])

file_to_output.close()

datu = open('to_save.csv',encoding= 'utf-8')

khali = csv.reader(datu)

new_csv = list(khali)
```

Comment: Please edit your question to post the complete error report starting with traceback. You can surround the report with 3` before and 3` after to properly format the output.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, your code working fine with me... However, this error usually happens when you have variables inside your code that resembles built-in objects in python ... so try to make some modifications in variable names ..
Good Luck